# Was there the potential for additional alternate supply routes to China toward the end of World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, china

For most of the war, the Allies airlifted a trickle of supplies to China from Assam (India) to Kuming (China) over the (Himalayan) ["Hump"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hump), enough to keep China in the war. In the winter of 1944-45, the Allies also managed to complete a road from India to the Allied-held portion of the [Burma Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma_Road) to China for land transportation.

If China had been a higher priority, were there additional ways routes through which China could have been supplied? For instance, after the early 1945 liberation of Manila Philippines, the Americans had an air base 2,500 kilometers from Chongqing (about the same distance as between Guam and Tokyo, travelled by long range B-29 bombers on round trips). And if the Americans had captured Formosa (Taiwan) in the fall of 1944 (possibly a less costly venture than the Philippines), they would have been about 1,000 air kilometers from Chongqing, roughly the same as the "over the Hump" route.

Did these two or others represent viable additional supply routes to China (one actual, one hypothetical) in early 1945?

Source for distances: Google.

In 1944, the Allies obtained near-total air supremacy over Europe. In fact, the whole point of the bombing campaign was to obtain this air superiority. I would imagine the same thing could have happened in Asia, given enough time.

Comment: Japanese air bases in China might have been a problem for American air transport?

Comment: That's a history-what-if scenario. We don't do that here, remember? 
China wasn't that important, defeating Japan had the priority.